# Symfony 4, PHPUnit - authorize user for unit test

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I'm writing test to do the unit testing of controller. I want to check if I get the proper content for the url, which requires user to be logged in.

I have following test written

```
class AdminControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testAdminHome(): void
    {
        $this->logIn();
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/');

        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Welcome to Admin Panel")')->count());
    }

    private function logIn()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setId(1);
        $user->setEmail('test@admin.com');
        $user->setFullName('Admin User');
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, ['ROLE_ADMIN']);
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
}
```

Configuration in my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: auto

    providers:
        database_users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/
            context: main

            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: admin_home

            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: security_login

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_EDITOR] }
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_EDITOR
        ROLE_EDITOR: ROLE_USER
```

However assertion for the Response code returns me 200, but I land on login page instead of admin home. Also there is not required content, as I'm on login page not an admin home.

Could you please check the code and help me find out the issue?

Comment: why you didn't persist your $user object ?

Comment: Why should I persist it? It's a unit test and I don't want to involve database to it.

Comment: Because the Security Component need the a refreshed user every time when generating token (interact with database), you can check it in profiler when you working in dev environment, so you must create a database in your test environment

Answer (score 0):

User @isom had right, I should have the user object persisted, so I have used fixtures to have a user persisted and then everything is fine. 
Instead of creating new user object I pull it from DB with following code:

```
$user = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository(User::class)->find(1);
```